# Determining the effective coefficient in a boundary value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

I'm trying to understand the setup given in [**Multiscale analytical solutions and homogenization of n-dimensional generalized elliptic equations**](http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/bitstream/10150/194912/1/azu_etd_1016_sip1_m.pdf), pg 41:

Given the boundary value problem:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( -K(x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)=0\text{ in } \Omega\equiv(0,1)$$
$$u(0)=0$$
$$u(1)=1$$
where $K(x)$ is a smooth, strictly positive function in $\Omega$.

We can consider the quantity $q^0 \equiv -K(x)\frac{du}{dx}$ to be a constant in $\Omega$, since the equation specifically states that $\frac{d}{dx}\left( q^0\right)=0$.  I understand that we can write:

$$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{q^0}{K(x)}$$
$$\Rightarrow u=\int_0^x -\frac{q^0}{K(\tau)} d\tau$$.

But the author claims that we can further rewrite this as:

$$u=K^0\int_0^x\frac{d\tau}{K(\tau)}$$  where  $$K^0=-q^0=\frac{1}{\int_0^1 \frac{d\tau}{K(\tau)}}$$.

It is not immediately apparent from the given information that we can deduce that $-q^0=\frac{1}{\int_0^1 \frac{d\tau}{K(\tau)}}$.  How could I have derived this from the given information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug the second boundary condition $u(1)=1$ into your formula 
$$u=\int_0^x -\frac{q^0}{K(\tau)} d\tau$$

Comment: Oh, I see now... It was staring at me in my face and I didn't even realize it.  So, using the derived formula, I can simply apply the condition $u(1)=1$ into the formula and solve for $-q_0$.  I can't believe it was that simple!  Thanks, PavelM.